# Attach a click listener to a menu item

Tags: javascript, extjs

I'm new to ExtJS so here goes. I'm creating a menu on the fly; the menu is only displayed when I click an element e.g. a button or image. The menu has two items I'd like to be able to execute specific functionality i.e. unique when any of the menu items is clicked.

```
var menu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.Menu', {
  bodyStyle: 'backgroundColor: #FFF;',
  renderTo: targetElement,
  showSeparator: false,
  floating: true,
  items: [
      { 
          // When clicked do A
          text: 'A',
          plain: true,
          cls: 'menu-item'
      },
      {
          // When clicked do B
          text: 'B',
          plain: true,
          cls: 'menu-item'
      }
  ]
});
```

I've tried attaching a click listener to each of the menu items but that doesn't seem to work see snippet below.

```
{ 
    // When clicked do A
    text: 'A',
    plain: true,
    cls: 'menu-item',
    listeners: {
      click: function(item, e, eOpts) {
         console.log("Foo");
      }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Removing **renderTo: targetElement,** and using **menu.showBy(targetElement, "tr-br", [0, -5]);** seemed to get the events firing.

Answer (score 0):

Use **menu.showBy()** after the menu is created to appropriately position the floating menu and omit the **renderTo** config when creating the menu.